# What is the difference between acoustic photon and acoustic phonon?

Tags: visible-light, photons, acoustics, definition, phonons

In the book Biomedical Photonics Handbook, 3 Volume Set edited by Tuan Vo-Dinh, it is written : Brillouin Scattering is caused by the interaction of the photon with the acoustic phonon. As the result of the intraction the wavelength of the radiation change.

And according to https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/acoustic-phonon , If energy is lost by the acoustic photon to the glass, the Brillouin shifted light is lower in frequency than the input light and is called Stokes light.

What is the difference between acoustic photon and acoustic phonon?

Comment: There is no such a thing as "acoustic photon". "Phonon" - yes, but not "photon".

Comment: But i saw this term been used several times on articles, do they mean phonon ? you can check it here : https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/acoustic-phonon where it has been employed many  times.

Comment: I saw it there, but it looks like the only place using this term. If you can find a definition for it elsewhere - I would be happy to learn.

Comment: Here The frequency of acoustic photon is determined by the following formula : w= 4πnv/λ  (http://www.scitepress.org/Papers/2015/55626/55626.pdf)

Comment: "Acoustic photon" just looks like an error to me, like they were using the words "acoustic", "phonon", and "photon" too much and got mixed up.

Comment: I believe that each instance of "acoustic photon" in that paper is likely an error. One of them definitely is, as it computes the frequency using the speed of sound, which would be relevant to a phonon, but not to a photon.

Given the number of places that "acoustic photon" appears in that paper, I'm guessing a search-and-replace gone wrong, or a confused editor, or something like that.

Comment: A photon is a quanta of light and a phonon a quanta of lattice vibration.  All phonons are acoustical phenomena.  There is such a thing as an optical branch in the dispersion relations.  Light can excite acoustic vibrations and if there are charges on the lattice acoustic vibrations will radiate, create photons.  There is a whole host of processes where light and lattice vibrations interact.  Could it be a photon created by charged phonon collision?  I see you added a reference but can you find more?